# get text value from <ul> <li> elements after click on it

Tags: angular, typescript

As you can see I have list of items, for now I can pass .innerTXT to

tag of any item i click, but When I click some nested item for example statistics -> tests, I want to display whole path not only 'tests', Can someone help me to fix it out ?

The thing I've done so far, but it displays whole list not single clicked element

```
    document.getElementById("menu-content").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
      const input = event.target as HTMLElement;
      console.log(input.nodeName);
      if(e.target && input.nodeName == "LI") {
        (document.getElementById('txt') as HTMLElement).innerHTML = input.innerText;
      }
    });
```

```
    <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">

      <li id="node1" ><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard </li>
      <li id="node2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#statistics" class="collapsed">
        <i class="fa fa-area-chart fa-lg"></i> Statistics <span class="arrow"></span>
      </li>

      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="statistics">
        <li id="node21">Tests</li>
        <li id="node23">Devices</li>
        <li id="node24">Builds</li>
        <li id="node25">Services</li>
        <li id="node26">Projects</li>
      </ul>

      <li id="node3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#reports" class="collapsed">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-lg"></i> Reports <span class="arrow"></span>
      </li>

      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="reports">
        <li>Tests</li>
        <li>Devices</li>
        <li>Builds</li>
        <li>Services</li>
        <li>Projects</li>
      </ul>

      <li id="node4"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-lg"></i> Configurations </li>

      <li id="node5" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#overview" class="collapsed">
        <i class="fa fa-book fa-lg"></i> Overview <span class="arrow"></span>
      </li>

      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="overview">
        <li>Tests</li>
        <li>Devices</li>
        <li>Builds</li>
        <li>Services</li>
        <li>Projects</li>
      </ul>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. I built this according to your question but you can modify it to make it more dynamic.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpfat5

html

```
  <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="statistics">
    <li *ngFor="let item of listItems;let i = index" (click)="onItemClick('statistics',i)">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
```

component

```
 listItems = ['Tests','Devices','Builds','Services','Projects'];
  onItemClick(category:string, index: number)
  {
    console.log(`${category} -> ${this.listItems[index]}`)
  }
```